# New Microsoft.NET.Sdk projects build output files in subdirectories. How to change it back?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, target-framework

Recently upgraded an old version of an open source project. The new project file is is the newer SDK project type, and i'm having a problem with something that should be super simple.

When building the old project, the output files were copied directly into the folder I specified in the project properties, build tab, "Output Path" field. Which I specified as either bin\x64\Debug or bin\x64\Release depending on the Configuration.

With this new project format, however, the actual DLLs are output into bin\x64\Debug\net461 instead. If I change the target framework, the output file is in a different location. bin\x64\Debug\net462 for instance.

I need it to never copy to the framework subdirectory. It royally screws up the nmake build scripts we use. How do I fix this?

What's more, the build directory is FULL of useless dependency DLLs copied from God knows where. I don't want anything in the output directory except the output.

How do I go about making this new project format work like the old one?

Answer (score 9):

Add it to your csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

`AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath` controls framework name
`AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath` controls x64/x86